# Spring Rest Exception Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I have a class

```
@Document(collection="emp_data") 
public class Employee{
    String name; 

    @Id 
    String id; 

    List<Skill> skills;
    //getter/setters 

    public static class Skill{
        String name;
        Integer level;
    }
}
```

My JSON is

```
{"id":"XXX","name":"john","skills":[{"name":"football","level":0}]}
```

When I POST this to a

> @RestController class  The createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp)
>   method

I get the following exception
Spring Rest Exception Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT
This is while de-serializing the skills collection, I tried to debut the JAckson ObjectMapper is throwing this exception when BeanDeserialiser try to deserialise the object.

> If any one can share a sample working object and controller with a ComplexObject containing List

Comment: works for me. check for any special character in your json. may be there is encoding problem esp for double quotes

Comment: Could you add a working code in post.. I am able to convert to and from Jason to Java object, using a test program ObjectMapper but doesn't work with spring rest. There are no special characters. If I remove skills from json the message is accepted well..

Comment: Did some more debugging got the the instantiation of BeanDeserialiser the _vanila property set to false in SpringRest while its 'true' in case of my TestJackson program.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of some clashing jars removed FreeMarker dependencies and cleaned my workspace the error is gone!
Although now stuck in sending a complex object in get request.